# How many waves do I have to survive to get an increase in galactic readiness?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I was playing around a bit in multiplayer mode alone in a private game to try out some stuff and noticed that I don't get any improvement in galactic readiness if I fail in one of the early waves.

So I wondered how many waves I do have to survive to get some increase to galactic readiness? I assume that I only get the full bonus if I finish all waves, but from which wave on do I at least get a partial bonus? And how much of the maximum bonus do I get at each possible step?

I did a quick experiment myself and didn't get anything for dying during the third wave, so there seems to be some minimum requirement before you get any increase in galactic readiness.

Comment: I'd love to SCIENCE this but I play in public games

Comment: I'd say 5 waves, I can't say for sure, but try it and see.

Comment: I'm pretty sure on Bronze on Random Location, Random Enemy at least that you get 1% toward all zones for every "objective" wave completed (3, 6 and 10), with a possible bonus if you make it to extraction.  Can't confirm anymore, as I'm 100%, but next time I'm below I'll try to be more observant.

Comment: @Teryx that sounds possible. I think it's about 4-5% for all zones if you get a 100% + clean extraction

Comment: I agree with @Teryx, I think you have to complete an objective wave in order to get any kind of readiness.

Answer (score 1):

Completing objective levels will raise your readiness.

Answer (score 1):

### ME3 Multiplayer Galactic Readiness Galaxy At War points / percentage increase mechanics per match / wave

## These options does not affect galactic readiness points

- Bronze or Silver or Gold or Platinum or Any Difficulty.
- Reaper or Cerberus or Geth or Collector or Random Enemy.
- When you quit a mission or get kicked out (90 seconds idle in a public match) of a mission then you don't get any points, xp or credits.
- When your team dies, you get points for completed objectives, XP and credits.

## Random map

- Gives points to all sectors (max = 3 x 5 = 15 points per match).
- +1 for every completed objective.

#### 6th wave strategy (team death after completing objective in wave 6)

It takes 6 waves easy to get first 2 points and 5 tougher waves to get the last point.

- PROS: fast killing because of easy enemies in early waves.
- CONS: In a    public match, it may be difficult to get your team
  killed after    completing         the objective of the 6th wave.

## Specific map

- Gives points to map-specific sector (max = 7 points per match).
- +1 after 3rd wave objective.
- +2 after 6th wave objective.
- +4 after 10th wave objective.

Answer (score 0):

Finishing games set on Unknown Map will give you 3% Readiness across the board (1% per objective), whilst playing on specific maps will net you 5% Readiness on that sector only.

BTW, not completing an objective will cause a Mission Failed, so it's not like you can skip doing objectives and still extract.

Answer (score 0):

Silver (I do not play bronze) random enemy/random map gives you 3% readiness bonus.  There are 3 objective waves, each one gives you 1% of the bonus as you are doing something that affects the region (stealing data, stopping data upload, killing high priority targets, ect).  Extraction is just relating to points, logically thinking of it like star wars, as long as you blow up the death star the region is more secure.  Its unfortunate not to have hero's around to show off.  Urns are just not the same as live hero's.